# Using array of swift generics in method with swift5

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

```
protocol AnimalFeed {
    init()
}

protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Feed: AnimalFeed
    func eat(_ food: Feed)
}

struct Hay: AnimalFeed {}
struct Carrot: AnimalFeed {}

struct Cow: Animal {
    func eat(_ food: Hay) {
        print("I eat hay")
    }
}

struct Rabbit: Animal {
    func eat(_ food: Carrot) {
        print("I eat carrot")
    }
}

struct Farm {
    func feed<T: Animal>(_ animal: T) {
        animal.eat(T.Feed())
    }

    func feedAll<T: Animal>(_ animals: [T]) {
        animals.forEach { feed($0)}
    }
}

let farm = Farm()
farm.feed(Rabbit())
farm.feedAll([Cow(), Rabbit()])
```

The last line results in an error: *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context*
How do we work around this?
I want to be able to pass an array of structs which conform to Animal protocol.

Comment: You need type erasure. [This](https://robnapier.net/erasure) excellent article explains it in detail.

Comment: Watch “Embrace Swift Generics” from WWDC 2022. Swift 5.7 will provide a smart solution with `any Animal`

Comment: @Jessy Of course it's available only in Xcode 14 (beta). Did you watch the video?

Comment: @vadian I did get this to compile, just not in a playground, or without [writing more closures](https://forums.swift.org/t/inconsistent-ergonomics-with-implicitly-opened-existentials-key-path-closures-vs-functions/58008).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This cannot be done in Swift 5.5

when you write

```
func feedAll<T: Animal>(_ animals: [T]) {
    animals.forEach { feed($0)}
}
```

you're saying, "Farm can feed an array of *any one Animal*." The compiler looks for a single type conforming to Animal, Cow, and Rabbit, and can't find it. What you really want is, "Farm can feed an array of any objects conforming to Animal."

```
func feedAll(_ animals: [Animal]) {
    animals.forEach { feed($0) }
}
```

But this angers Swift 5.5

> Protocol 'Animal' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
>
> Protocol 'Animal' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself

You can work around this by constructing a "box" type that captures the inner type (often called type erasure) and explicitly wrap each animal in your array in a box. For example

```
struct AnimalFeeder {
    let feed: () -> Void

    init<T: Animal>(_ animal: T) {
        feed = {
            animal.eat(T.Feed())
        }
    }
}

func feedAll(_ animals: [AnimalFeeder]) {
    animals.forEach { $0.feed() }
}

farm.feedAll([AnimalFeeder(Cow()), AnimalFeeder(Rabbit())])
```

Comment: @Jessy my apologies. I have removed the sentence about Swift 5.7